# LAContext evaluatePolicy:localizedReason:reply: errors with LAErrorUserCancel when user doesn't cancel

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, touch-id

I am trying to implement Touch ID on my app:

```
LAContext *ctx = [[LAContext alloc] init];
[ctx evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics localizedReason:@"Authenticate to access." reply:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    if(success){
       ...
    }else{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            switch (error.code) {
                case LAErrorTouchIDNotAvailable:
                case LAErrorUserFallback:
                    self.passwordPanel.hidden = NO;
                    break;

                default:
                    //we hit here with error code -2
            }
        });
    }
}];
```

This is an in-house app that is currently used by 5 users. Four people including me (with a mix of iPhone 6 and iPhone 5s devices), have no problems. The last user (also having an iPhone 6) constantly hits the `default` case and their error code is -2, which is set to `LAErrorUserCancel`. The problem is that, they are hitting it instantly when `evaluatePolicy` is called, without even being able to scan their finger or tap cancel.

Why would this happen?

Comment: What does `[ctx canEvaluatePolicy...]` return for this user?

Comment: @Paulw11 I am unable to test it at the moment as I don't have access to that very device, but I know that they are using Touch ID on the device and it's working.

Comment: Did you ever find out?

Comment: @hfossli nope. after trying everything, i've abandoned it.

Comment: Is the context invalidated since there is no longer a reference to it?

Comment: I honestly have no idea. I've given up on that project, it's been more than 6 years. But yup it might be related to scoping.